# Is there a reliable directory watcher that can be used to run shell commands on any modification?

Tags: watchkit, watch, inotify, fswatch

I am looking for a tool (preferably X platform) that can watch a directory's entire tree and run shell commands when it happens.

I have tried many tools prior, such as `fswatch`, `chokidar`, `findr`...

But they have quirk issues, e.g. some of these command terminates when a file in the watched directory is removed.

Is there a tool that I am missing on? It would be best if the tool is X platform.

Answer (score 0):

https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/watchman-make.html

(disclosure: I'm the creator of Watchman)